# How to use Correlation-ID with Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast 3.8.1 java client for sending *Map*, *Queue* in Hazelcast instance.

I am using below approach for sending my data, please have a look on my sample below:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("groupname").setPassword("pass");
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("localhost:5701");
HazelcastInstance hazelcast = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
... hazelcast put in Map, Queue
... hazelcast get from Map, Queue
```

In the above example, I would like to send data in Map, queue with CorrelationID and my other Java client will send me a response back to other Map, Queue. And I would like to read that response based on the same CorrelationID I passed. [Hazelcast-CorrelationId](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/protocol/1.0-developer-preview/client-protocol.html#HazelcastOpenBinaryClientProtocol-DeveloperPreview-CorrelationID)

How can I use **CorrelationID** here ?
I would like to know How **CorrelationID** work in Hazelcast?

Comment: Which "CorrelationID" do you mean? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/protocol/1.0-developer-preview/client-protocol.html#HazelcastOpenBinaryClientProtocol-DeveloperPreview-CorrelationID

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use CorrelationID in your regular operations such as `IMap.put`. It is related to Hazelcast's client protocol, which is used for developing new clients in different programming languages. To track the data you sent/received, you can put another field in your entity objects rather than using Hazelcast's internals.

Comment: Will be the same case with Queue as well?

Comment: Yes, it is the same for Queue as well.